# Small Pimple like structure in lips?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology

Is this some  kind of disease ? I saw this in one of my family member
Usually it is totally not visible  but whenever the lips are stretched they are seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there are so many, thier location (on the lips, where hair is *not* present), and overall appearance, I'm almost certain that those are harmless, [fordyce spots](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fordyce_spots?wprov=sfla1), which are basically just oil producing (sebaceous) glands.

They tend to form (come and go) as someone gets older with age, with nearly 80% of adults experiencing this condition at some point. See [here](http://oatext.com/pdf/CCRR-1-140.pdf) for further details.

NOTE: The link just provided does contain an image of an isolated region of a scrotum.